# Is it possible to perform multiple SADD or ZADD assignments with a single .sadd/.zadd call in ioredis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm using ioredis to cache and index a large amount of data, and thus far I haven't been able to find any documentation that indicates I can do multiple SADDs from a single call.

Is it possible, and, if so, is there any performance advantage to it? At the moment, I'm using a `multi()` call and looping to add multiple indexed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can. From the [ioredis README, Basic Usage](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#basic-usage):

```
// Arguments to commands are flattened, so the following are the same:
redis.sadd('set', 1, 3, 5, 7);
redis.sadd('set', [1, 3, 5, 7]);
```

Comment: True. I totally missed this. Thanks.